# Unable to use extensions in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code gives errors when i try to use extensions in my flutter app

[image: visual studio screenshot]

and i guess i have required version of dart installed

[image]

As per the first error i have enabled experiments in `analysis_options.yaml` (suggested in [this link](https://quickbirdstudios.com/blog/dart-extension-methods/) )

[image]

Please suggest if i am going wrong anywhere or missing the inclusion of any dependencies?

Comment: What sdk required version is defined in your pubspec.yaml file? If you allow a version without extensions, you cannot use extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You have a correct version of Flutter/Dart, which should have extension methods enabled.
Are you *sure* that your VS Code is using *that* version?

Try opening "settings" in VS Code (File > Preferences > Settings) and enter (copy) the following into the search field:

```
@ext:dart-code.dart-code sdkPath
```

This should show a number of entries, `Dart: Sdk path(s)` and `Dart: Flutter Sdk path(s)`. If any of these are set, it might be used instead of the Flutter SDK that you see on the command line.